# Issue with HTML form submit button not calling Google script function

Tags: html

I've made a google script which I've published as a web app. I want the "myFunction()" to be called when I press the submit button on the web app. The following doesn't seem to work, and I can't really tell why:

google script file:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function myFunction() {

  //does some stuff

}
```

html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="Code.gs"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myform">
    <!-- some input stuff goes here -->
    <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Update" onclick="myFunction()" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you know that the function is called?  Is your `Code.gs` in the same directory as your HTML file (if not, it will not be included).  Put a test `alert()` or `console.log()` as the very first line in `myFunction()`, to see if the function is actually getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it through just a few seconds of Google Search, In your HTML file include the following...

```
<script>
  google.script.run.myFunction();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using:

```
<input name="submit"  type="button" value="update" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

Because, when you write type="submit" the values of the form are sended, and ignore onclick